# Add a static label/text above panel

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a laravel nova panel and its working fine. However I would like to have a static label/text above the panel saying "Read more section". Do you know if nova has some component or field or something to achieve that? Thanks!

```
  public function fields(Request $request)
        {
            return [
                ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),
    
                new Panel('Read more section', [                
    
                    JSON::make('Read more section', [
                        Text::make('Title')->rules(['max:255']),
                        Text::make('Description'),
                    ])  
                ]),
                
               
            ];
        }
```

Comment: What is not working here? Because looking at docs, the way you described would be the way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, but don't know why the "Read more section" title doesn't appear. So I wanted to add some other element to add the title to see if it would work. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://novapackages.com/packages/naoray/nova-json) (`under 'use-inside-panels', you need to scoll, link does not work`)

Because you're using the JSON Wrapper, defining fields in a Panel is a bit different. Your code should be as follow:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
        {
            return [
                ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),
    
                new Panel('Read more section', [                
    
                    JSON::make('Read more section', [
                        Text::make('Title')->rules(['max:255']),
                        Text::make('Description'),
                    ])->data // <-- added data.
                ]),
                
               
            ];
        }
```

Please refer to the docs here: [docs](https://novapackages.com/packages/naoray/nova-json) (`under 'use-inside-panels', you need to scoll, link does not work`)

Comment: Thanks! But like that it shows "exception: "BadMethodCallException"
file: "/var/www/html/vendor/naoray/nova-json/src/JSON.php"
".

Comment: I also have a " Flexible::make('Images')
                        ->addLayout('Images', 'image', [
                            Text::make('Image URL', 'image_url'),
                            Text::make('Image Text', 'image_text'),
                        ])
                        ->button('Add Image')," field within the JSON. I didn't add it to the question because probably its not relevant but probably it is, not sure.

Comment: I mucked up, sorry, it should not be `data()` but `data`, let me update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Like that it shows "file: "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/nova/src/Panel.php"
line: 79
message: "Attempt to assign property \"panel\" on array"".

Comment: No sure why that happens, also have no access to Nova source code so I can't look into the problem. What is line 79? Any way I can access docs?

Comment: With "...JSON::make('Read more section', [" it works, not exactly why. Thanks

Comment: But, that's what you had? `JSON::make('Read more section', [ ] )` ?

Comment: Yes, just added ... before JSON and it worked. Thanks!